# How to serve gitbook on 0.0.0.0 instead of localhost?

Tags: gitbook

For dev purpose I want to run gitbook in a docker container which expose port 4000.

**How to start dev server on 0.0.0.0 instead of 127.0.0.1 ?**

```
gitbook server
Serving book on http://localhost:4000
```

Comment: Which image are you using? Can you not just map the container port on your host port? `-p 4000:4000` Your server will still be hosted on localhost inside the container which is normal, but you can access it from the outside.

Comment: When gitbook is listening on 127.0.0.1 the service is only bound to the loopback interface. Only available inside the container image, not on the host. My port is correctly configured: expose 4000 in Dockerfile and -p 4000:4000 in my docker run command.

Comment: I'm probably not fully into the issue, but isn't it the goal of docker to keep your service only inside your docker container? If you don't want to use containerized networking you can urn your gitbook using the `--net` option without mapping the port. Just open the port in the firewall.